# Windows 10: Change taskbar icon of an UWP app

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, desktop-customization

Is there any way of changing the icon of a pinned to taskbar UWP application in Windows 10? Like Skype Preview or Groove?

I didn't find any way to do it, and the searches in Google always point to old Windows or Win32 applications. I did try to create a shortcut and change it's icon (this works), but it can't be dragged to the taskbar, and if you pin the app it always puts the default icon.

I also tried to put the shortcut directly in the taskbar shortcuts folder (`%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`), but the UWP apps doesn't seem to appear there. The rest of applications can be easily customized from that folder.

Also, I guess there is still no way to pin Edge websites shortcuts to the taskbar, even with the Anniversary Update, right?

Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 2):

This was driving me crazy as well so, after doing a lot of searching and trial and error, I’ve managed to create a guide to change the icons in the taskbar that works on any app, either UWP or Win32.
And I thought to share it here, maybe it will be useful to others as well:
https://dpcdpc11.com/custom-taskbar-icons-guide/

There are a few steps that involve a third-party app used to change the AppID of a custom shortcut, but if you follow along closely, you'll see that it works.
I even have an example in the guide to make things easier.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a simple workaround for pinning websites to the taskbar. Create a new shortcut and paste the following as the target:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k start https://www.example.com && exit
```

(opens in default browser)

or

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k start microsoft-edge:https://www.example.com && exit
```

(always opens in Edge)

Set "Run" to "minimized" and pin it to the taskbar. You probably also want to change the icon (btw you can get the .ico icon of a website by copying it from a Chrome website-shortcut).

**EDIT:**

You can use the same method for pinning UWP app shortcuts with custom icons to the taskbar. You have to put the shortcut of the UWP somewhere (by dragging it from the start menu). So let's say you have a UWP App called "Example App" on the desktop. Then you create a shortcut with the target

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Example App.lnk" && exit
```

Then set "Run" to "minimized", add your custom icon and pin it to the taskbar.

Comment: Hmmm, this works, but when the program launches, it runs the default icon again, not quite what I was looking for :)